# How do I make C-x b (switch-to-buffer) ignore some buffers?

Tags: buffers, interactive

I want `C-x b` (i.e. `switch-to-buffer`) to ignore some buffers. For example, I want to ignore `*Ibuffer*`. In other words, when I press `C-x b`, I should not see `Switch to buffer (default *Ibuffer*):` . `*Ibuffer*` should be skipped. Is there a way to make `C-x b` ignore particular buffers?

Comment: See:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989072/exclude-hated-buffers-from-switch-to-buffer-list

Answer (score 2):

Command `switch-to-buffer` is designed to do just what it does. You can advise it to do something different, but typically if you want different behavior for a given key sequence then you are better off using a different command.

(This is all the more true in the case of `switch-to-buffer`, which is used not only as a command, i.e., interactively, but from Lisp code in many places, including in the core Emacs code.)

What you're interested in is the interactive part: the part that reads a buffer name from you. That's realized for `switch-to-buffer` by function `read-buffer-to-switch`. But that function is hard-coded to exclude only the current buffer. That function in turn is defined using function `read-buffer`, which, fortunately, offers more possibilities.

You can define a command that uses `read-buffer` in a way that provides only the buffer-name choices you want, and then bind that command to `C-x b`.

`C-h f read-buffer` tells you that there's a `PREDICATE` argument that filters the list of available buffers to present only some of them.  Use that.

This code reuses the `interactive` spec from `switch-to-buffer`, except that it uses `read-buffer` with a predicate that excludes buffer `*Ibuffer*`:

```lisp
(defun my-switch-to-buffer (buffer-or-name &optional norecord force-same-window)
  "Switch to another buffer, besides `*Ibuffer*'."
  (interactive
   (let ((force-same-window
          (cond
           ((window-minibuffer-p) nil)
           ((not (eq (window-dedicated-p) t)) 'force-same-window)
           ((pcase switch-to-buffer-in-dedicated-window
              (`nil (user-error
                     "Cannot switch buffers in a dedicated window"))
              (`prompt
               (if (y-or-n-p
                    (format "Window is dedicated to %s; undedicate it"
                            (window-buffer)))
                   (progn
                     (set-window-dedicated-p nil nil)
                     'force-same-window)
                 (user-error
                  "Cannot switch buffers in a dedicated window")))
              (`pop nil)
              (_ (set-window-dedicated-p nil nil) 'force-same-window))))))
     (list (read-buffer "Buffer: "
                        (other-buffer (current-buffer))
                        (confirm-nonexistent-file-or-buffer)
                        (lambda (name.buf)
                          (not (string= "*Ibuffer*" (car name.buf))))))))
  (switch-to-buffer buffer buffer-or-name norecord force-same-window))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x b") 'my-switch-to-buffer)
```